# How can I download HTML from website like browser would (autoremembered data) in Java

Tags: java, html, facebook

Okay, so what I want to do is to download HTML from facebook from Java code.
I know how to do that, the problem comes when I want it to download HTML as I would in `View page source` in my browser, when I'm logged in instead of getting the login fb page.

I know that I can use API but I just want to check one thing in HTML and it seems like kinda too big thing to include and use a whole API.

So I was wondering if there is a simple way of doing that (maybe I should execute some link first with my credentials, although I don't think that it is the way to do that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  I want to do is to download HTML from facebook from JAVA code
```

You can do that by reading from a Urlconnection.

```
  import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class URLConnectionReader {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            URL facebook = new URL("http://www.facebook.com/or any dir");
            URLConnection yc = facebook.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                        yc.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            in.close();
        }
    }
```

You can input any url and get the source code of that given page.

To view the source code or save the source code.

```
java URLConnectionReader > facebook.html(or any format)
```

> The problems comes when I want to download HTML as it would be if I
>   were Logged in (But of course I'm not, it just downloads the login
>   page). And I don't know how to kind of progmatically login, so that I
>   can download the HTML as it would be after I've logged in

First a word of caution, if you don't have direct permission to do this, beware, the site in question may preclude this in their terms of service.

To answer the question, there are many, many reasons a site would reject a login. To do this successfully you need to get as close as possible to how a browser would handle the transaction. To do that you need to see what a real browser is doing.

https is more tricky as many http sniffers can't deal with it but httpwatch claims it can. Check out the HTTP transactions and then try to replicate them.

Your url.openConnection() call will actually return an instance of HTTPURLConnction, cast to that & then you'll be able to easily set various http headers such as the User-Agent.

A final note, you say a cookie may be required. Your code isn't going to deal with cookies. To do that you'll need to use a cookie manager, e.g.:[refer this for example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/cookies/index.html)

Comment: Yeah, as I wrote in the next sentence after the one you quoted I know how to do that. That's not the problem.

Comment: ok so will you please elaborate?the problem comes when I want it to download HTML as I would in View page source in my browser?what exactly are you asking @user3212350(happy to help)

Comment: The problems comes when I want to download HTML as it would be if I were Logged in (But of course I'm not, it just downloads the login page). And I don't know how to kind of progmatically login, so that I can download the HTML as it would be after I've logged in

Comment: Edited my Aswer@user3212350 facebook surely work with cookies . so do refer the link.